# Rolling column subtraction of Dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, multiple-columns, subtraction

I have a dataframe like this one:

```
library(lubridate)
set.seed(23) 

date_list = seq(ymd('2000-01-15'),ymd('2010-09-18'),by='day')
testframe = data.frame(Date = date_list)
testframe$Day = substr(testframe$Date, start = 6, stop = 10)
testframe$ABC = rnorm(3900)
testframe$DEF = rnorm(3900)
testframe$GHI = seq(from = 10, to = 25, length.out = 3900)
testframe$JKL = seq(from = 5, to = 45, length.out = 3900)
```

I want to have an automatic rolling subset of this dataframe, that should be like this:

```
testframe_ABC = testframe[,c("Date","Day","ABC")]
testframe_DEF = testframe[,c("Date","Day","DEF")]
testframe_GHI = testframe[,c("Date","Day","GHI")]
testframe_JKL = testframe[,c("Date","Day","JKL")]
```

The columns Date and Day should always stay, the other columns should be added individually. The name of the varying column should be added to the dataframename, to have a new df. All dataframes could also be in a list of dataframes, if possible.

Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: do we really need 3900 rows? Try and make your examples minimal please.

Comment: No, sorry. I just used this example again, since I have several question related to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want a list of 4 data frames whose components are `ABC`, `DEF`, etc. It would be better to put them in a list:

```
L <- Map(function(nm) testframe[c("Date", "Day", nm)], names(testframe)[-(1:2)])
```

in which case `L$ABC` or `L[[1]]` will refer to the `ABC` data frame but if you  want to leave them dangling in the global environment this will copy the list components to it:

```
list2env(L, .GlobalEnv)
```

I would not use the term `rolling` in this context.  Typically that term refers to a sliding window such as this:

```
library(zoo)
rollmeanr(1:10, 3)  # 2 is mean of 1:3, 3 is mean of 2:4, etc.
## [1] 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `split.default` to split on every column and then `cbind` the first 2 columns to every element, i.e.

```
lapply(split.default(testframe[-c(1, 2)], seq_along(testframe)[-c(1, 2)]), function(i)
                                                cbind.data.frame(testframe[c(1, 2)], i))
```

which gives a list,

```
$`3`
        Date   Day        ABC
1 2000-01-15 01-15  0.1932123
2 2000-01-16 01-16 -0.4346821
3 2000-01-17 01-17  0.9132671

$`4`
        Date   Day       DEF
1 2000-01-15 01-15 1.7933881
2 2000-01-16 01-16 0.9966051
3 2000-01-17 01-17 1.1074905

$`5`
        Date   Day  GHI
1 2000-01-15 01-15 10.0
2 2000-01-16 01-16 17.5
3 2000-01-17 01-17 25.0

$`6`
        Date   Day JKL
1 2000-01-15 01-15   5
2 2000-01-16 01-16  25
3 2000-01-17 01-17  45
```

**DATA USED**

```
dput(testframe)
structure(list(Date = structure(c(10971, 10972, 10973), class = "Date"), 
    Day = c("01-15", "01-16", "01-17"), ABC = c(0.193212333898146, 
    -0.434682108206693, 0.913267096589322), DEF = c(1.79338809206353, 
    0.996605106833546, 1.10749048744809), GHI = c(10, 17.5, 25
    ), JKL = c(5, 25, 45)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```